# Как исправить ошибку "vncserver: The HOME environment variable is not set" - запустить скрипт Python из PHP от имени пользователя?

Tags: apache, centos, vnc

Скрипт на **Python** запускаю из **PHP**. Скрипт запускается нормально, но доходя до строчек запуска **vncserver** - не может его запустить:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.8
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import time
import requests
from datetime import datetime
from pymongo import MongoClient
from multiprocessing import Pool
import json
import math 
import subprocess
import os
SCRIPT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
.
.
.

    ## VNC Display checks
    # Configure DISPLAY variable to VNC
    os.environ["DISPLAY"] = cfg["vnc_display"]
    if os.system("xhost >& /dev/null"):
        print("WARNING: No VNC display opened under %s. Running VNC Server and trying again" % (os.environ["DISPLAY"]))
        os.system("vncserver %s" % (os.environ["DISPLAY"]))
        time.sleep(5)
        if os.system("xhost >& /dev/null"):
            print("ERROR: No VNC display opened under %s. Cannot continue" % (os.environ["DISPLAY"]))
            return
.
.
.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    command_line_runner()
```

вываливает ошибку:

**vncserver: The HOME environment variable is not set

No VNC display opened under :1.

Running VNC Server and trying again.

ERROR: No VNC display opened under :1.

Cannot continue.**

Как я понимаю **vncserver** не хочет запускаться с правами пользователя **Apache**, а только из под пользователя - ошибка связана с правами на исполнение. Т.к. если запускать скрипт напрямую, в командной строке, от имени пользователя - ошибок нет и все работает нормально.
**ВОПРОС:**  как запустить скрипт **Python** из **PHP** от имени пользователя и добиться запуска **vncserver**?
Я думаю что все таки нужно как то научить скрипт работать правильно с правами **Apache**, но не знаю как это сделать. Предложите пожалуйста варианты решения. Спасибо.

Comment: 1. для запуска процесса от имени другого пользователя служит программа sudo. 2. в приведённом сообщении написано, что не установлена переменная окружения HOME. так установите её. значение получить [совсем несложно](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4028943/4827341)

Comment: 1. целевой **Python**-скрипт исполняется из **PHP**, а значит с правами **Apach** - не совсем понял вас каким образом тут использовать **sudo**?
2. суть в том, что при запуске этого же скрипта через консоль **CentOS7** скрипт отрабатывет как нужно и без ошибок. Значение **HOME** получаю так: **SCRIPT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))**

Comment: 1. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1150340/178576 2. я же привёл ссылку, как можно получить путь к домашнему каталогу пользователя. не заметили? хорошо, повторю: [это ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4028943/4827341)