# Не получается использовать rfcomm под обычным пользователем в Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, com-port

Система Ubuntu 20.04. Устройство bluetooth сканер штрихкода, который эмулирует com порт. У меня не получается использовать rfcomm под обычным пользователем

> rfcomm connect hci0  00:20:E0:7F:43:0A 1
> **Can't connect RFCOMM socket: Permission denied**

Под sudo все прекрасно работает. Включил пользователя во все возможные группы, но эффекта нет. Что нужно сделать чтобы заработало?

Если пытаюсь подключится из Гнома Blueman-applet 2.1.2 (Подключить: Serial port) то тогда вообще подвисает подключение, т.е. пишет соединение и больше ничего, пока не перезагрузишь сервис bluetooth. При этом другие устройства, например телефон, прекрасно подключаются.

Comment: разрешите пользователю выполнять от имени пользователя root [только указанную вами программу](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18830/110559)

Comment: Во первых, как это сделать? А во-вторых, почему так получается? Это такая особенность bluetooth или же я все таки неправильно что то делаю.

Comment: 1. я же ссылку привёл с примером. непонятно? хорошо, напишу в ответе. 2. не знаю. ещё возможные варианты: а) устройство сообщает о себе некорректную информацию и сбивает с толку bluez; б) редкая ошибка где-то в стеке bluez, проявившаяся именно с вашим устройством.

Comment: 1. Прошу прощения что не заметил ссылку сразу. Теперь понятно как запустить. Но получается все равно нужно писать sudo, правильно я понял?Значит если какая то другая программа запускает эту же команду, то работать все равно не будет, т.к. sudo там нет.

Comment: 2. так впишите нужную команду. не `rfcomm параметры`, а `sudo rfcomm параметры`. // судя по приведённой вами информации, вам нужно, чтобы пользователь «просто ткнул куда-то по инструкции и всё заработало». ну так создайте пользователю ярлык с нужной командой. в меню или на т.н. «рабочем столе».

Comment: 2. Я правильно понимаю, что rfcomm в blutz не используется? У меня подключить сканер и получить COM порт получилось настроить (пусть только у root) а вот подключить сканер в Gnome (под root) через аплет никак не получается, ну com порта естественно нет. Через **bluetoothctl** тоже не могу подключить `Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.NotAvailable` хотя спарить прекрасно получается. Есть какая то возможность понять что мешает подключению? А то в логах нет ничего (или смотрю не там), а сообщение что я привел мне ничего не говорит.

Comment: если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом вернем углу страницы. если надо указать контекст, можете привести ссылку на данный вопрос

Comment: Дак вот не получается ничего, хоть я и подключаюсь и КОМ порт создается (командой rfcomm) но 1С все равно ничего не получает почему то, может механизм rfcomm устаревший. Возможно надо подключится из апплета, а там ничего не подключает.

Comment: Какой вопрос новый? Я вроде про одну проблему пишу.

Comment: этот сайт — не техподдержка и здесь не «решают проблемы». здесь база знаний: вопросы и ответы на них. главное — чтобы ответы были полезны не только одному человеку, задавшему вопрос, а другим, кто будет разыскивать ответы на аналогичный вопрос. вы сейчас как минимум ещё два вопроса озвучили, к текущему не имеющие никакого отношения (кроме того, что вы с ними разбираетесь): 1. не работает ваша программма со считывателем штрих-кодов, хотя тот и благополучно подключился. 2 не работает сканер.

Comment: Советуемый способ с `sudo` — это лютый хак и костыль. Чтобы работало от пользователя, его надо поместить в определённую группу, у которой есть доступ к _/dev/rfcomm_.

Comment: **Чтобы работало от пользователя, его надо поместить в определённую группу, у которой есть доступ к /dev/rfcomm** Только вот не работает предложенный вами вариант, запускается Только от root, пробовал добавлять пользователя во все группы которые были, но не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

для того, чтобы разрешить `пользователю1` выполнять указанную команду от имени другого `пользователя2` без ввода каких-либо паролей, можно добавить в файл с произвольным именем в каталоге `/etc/sudoers.d` такую примерно строку:

```
пользователь1 ALL = (пользователь2) NOPASSWD: команда
```

как правильно редактировать файлы `/etc/sudoers.d/*`, написано в [другом моём ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/552377/178576).

для вашего случая строка будет выглядеть так:

```
имя_пользователя ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/rfcomm параметры
```

полный путь к исполняемому файлу обязателен. если не указывать здесь конкретные параметры, то пользователь сможет передавать произвольный набор параметров.

---

теперь указанный пользователь сможет выполнить:

```
$ sudo /usr/bin/rfcomm параметры
```

без запроса пароля.

Comment: Почитайте на досуге как это делать правильно, а пока -1.

Answer (score 2):

Можно тогда сделать ещё проще:
`chmod 6755 /usr/bin/rfcomm или chmod ug+s+t /usr/bin/rfcomm`
Это позволяет запускать файл от имени владельца, но конечно безопасность в этом случае не очень.

Comment: если rfcomm не стартует новых процессов, то безопасность приемлима

Comment: Это ещё хуже, чем предложенное в другом ответе.

Comment: Почему хуже? Вы сами, какие то варианты предложите?